# How to generate a digital signature of a string in Python?

Tags: python, digital-signature

I have a string and I need to generate a digital signature for it using my private key? How can I do it in Python?

Comment: There are loads of documents available online for reference with PyCrypto that you should use as a basis. Including previous posts on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JoshDinsdale How sure are you that PyCrypto is still a good option? It looks rather dead to me.

Comment: I believe you could use [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) which is still [regularly updated](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography). I refer you to the [signing](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa/#signing) section for DSA, and the [signing](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing) section for RSA.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) module to [generate a private key](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.html#generation) then [sign your string](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.html#signing) using RSA:

```
# Generate a private key   
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
>>> private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
...     public_exponent=65537,
...     key_size=2048,
...     backend=default_backend()
... )

# Sign a message using the key
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
>>> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
>>> message = b"A message I want to sign"
>>> signature = private_key.sign(
...     message,
...     padding.PSS(
...         mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
...         salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
...     ),
...     hashes.SHA256()
... )
```

If you already have a private key that you want to use, then you can [load it](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.html#key-loading) rather than generating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete example, inspired by the current answer, expanded to show an actual example of `sign` and `verify`:

```
# pip install cryptography

import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding, PrivateFormat, NoEncryption
import cryptography

def rsa_keypair():
    private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=65537, key_size=2048, backend=default_backend())
    return (private_key, private_key.public_key())

def sign(message, private_key):
    padding_instance = padding.PSS(mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()), salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH)
    return base64.b64encode(private_key.sign(message, padding_instance, hashes.SHA256()))

def verify(message, signature, public_key):
    sig = base64.b64decode(signature)
    padding_instance = padding.PSS(mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()), salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH)
    try:
        public_key.verify(sig, message, padding_instance, hashes.SHA256())
        return True
    except cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature:
        return False

pvt1, pub1 = rsa_keypair()
pvt2, _    = rsa_keypair()

msg = b"Hello you!"
sig1 = sign(msg, pvt1) # signed with private key
sig2 = sign(msg, pvt2) # signed with *other* private key

res = verify(msg, sig1, pub1)
print(res)                    # True:  ok...     signed with the private key related to public key pub1
res = verify(msg, sig2, pub1)
print(res)                    # False: no! *not* signed with the private key related to public key pub1
```

Answer (score -3):

from **chat-gpt**

```
import hashlib

def generate_unique_signature(input_string):
    # Create a SHA-256 hash object
    sha256 = hashlib.sha256()

    # Update the hash object with the input string
    sha256.update(input_string.encode('utf-8'))

    # Get the hexadecimal representation of the hash
    signature = sha256.hexdigest()

    return signature

# Example usage:
input_string = "Hello, World!"
signature = generate_unique_signature(input_string)
print("Unique Signature:", signature)
```

Comment: This is a hash, not a digital cryptographic signature

Comment: You have to make a difference between digital signatures in cryptography and hashes. What you provide is definitely a hash and not a digital signature. When asking chatgpt for help, please make sure it gives you an answer which is consistent and coherent with the question being asked before you post it, otherwise your incorrect answer will mislead people who do not know the difference like you.